# While loop and MoveNext

Tags: php, mysql, nested

I need some advice on the best method of nesting sql queries. I wrote a new query to pull in additional info which works fine as a stand alone query, but when i try to put the MoveNext(); command in just before the original, it causes the page load to fail. I'll give an example below.

```
$new_query = "SELECT new_values,new_price
FROM new_table
WHERE new_options_id = 2
AND language = 1";

$new_result = $db->Execute($new_query); 
while (!$new_result->EOF){
$newdata = $new_result->fields['new_values']
$newprice = $new_result->fields['new_price'];

$original_query = "SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE orders_id = '$ship_order_id' and class = 'ot_subtotal'";
$original_result = $db->Execute($original_query);

SOME CODE IN HERE

while (!$original_result->EOF) {

MORE CODE HERE WITH SEVERAL {

RESULTS OF ORIGINAL QUERY ARE OUTPUT
RESULTS OF NEW QUERY ARE OUTPUT

$new_result->MoveNext();
$original_result->MoveNext();

}
} 

MORE CODE WITH CLOSING } FROM EARLIER CODE
```

The problem is that putting in the new MoveNext() and it's associated } kills the page load.
I did look at including the data collection of the new query into the original, but my SQL knowledge is limited. 
Is there another way around this so that i can loop through the results within the original loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you have mutliple queries, you need multiple statement objects otherwise you will remove the former result of the former statment if you re-use the former statement object with the second query.

Just introduce a second statement object and you should be fine.

Additionally you told not which database client library you're using so I can not give any specific suggestions.

Comment: Yes, but which client library? It's neither `mysqli` nor `PDO` from the syntax you use.

Comment: looks like a php ADO implementation of some sorts, might it be this one OP http://phplens.com/adodb/

Comment: Now you're asking something i can't answer. Anybody know which client library is used in Zen Cart??